# How to get the element data out of a list using beautiful soup?

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

The code below gets the html data into a list. I am trying to scrape a specific element called data-append-csv (example is: `data-append-csv="abbotco01"`) from the baseball reference page html link (see the code for the link):

Current Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import Comment
import pandas as pd
import os.path
import requests

r = requests.get("https://www.baseball-reference.com/leagues/majors/2021-standard-batting.shtml")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser") # try lxml
[x.extract() for x in soup.find_all(string=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment)) if 'id="div_players_standard_batting"' in x]
```

Current Environment Settings:

```
dependencies:
  - python=3.9.7
  - beautifulsoup4=4.11.1
  - jupyterlab=3.3.2
  - pandas=1.4.2
  - pyodbc=4.0.32
```

The end goal: Be able to have a pandas dataframe that has each element of data-append-csv from the html table.

| index | data-append-csv |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | abbotco01 |
| 1 | abreual01 |
| 2 | abreubr01 |

etc.

Comment: Since you're already using `pandas`, look into `pd.read_html()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First convert the string into an `BeautifulSoup` object and `.select('[data-append-csv]')`:

```
table = [x.extract() for x in soup.find_all(string=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment)) if 'id="div_players_standard_batting"' in x][0]
[(a.find_previous('th').text,a.get('data-append-csv')) for a in BeautifulSoup(table).select('[data-append-csv]')]
```

To ensure a correct join to your original data, try to scrape the rank as well in case that there is are rows without these attribute and the length of both dataframes will be different:

```
(a.find_previous('th').text,a.get('data-append-csv'))
```

Now you could create your dataframe from your list:

```
pd.DataFrame([(a.find_previous('th').text,a.get('data-append-csv')) for a in BeautifulSoup(table).select('[data-append-csv]')],columns=['Rk','data-append-csv'],dtype='object')
```

###### Example

Join your data to your initial dataframe and check last column:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import Comment
import pandas as pd
import requests

r = requests.get("https://www.baseball-reference.com/leagues/majors/2021-standard-batting.shtml")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
table = [x.extract() for x in soup.find_all(string=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment)) if 'id="div_players_standard_batting"' in x][0]

### create and clean dataframe 1
df1 = pd.read_html(table)[0]
df1 = df1[(~df1.Rk.isna()) & (df1.Rk != 'Rk')]
df1.set_index('Rk', inplace=True)

### create and clean dataframe 2
df2 = pd.DataFrame([(a.find_previous('th').text,a.get('data-append-csv')) for a in BeautifulSoup(table).select('[data-append-csv]')],columns=['Rk','data-append-csv'],dtype='object')
df2.set_index('Rk', inplace=True)

### join both dataframe
df1.join(df2).reset_index()
```

###### Output

|  | Rk | Name | Age | Tm | Lg | G | PA | AB | R | H | 2B | 3B | HR | RBI | SB | CS | BB | SO | BA | OBP | SLG | OPS | OPS+ | TB | GDP | HBP | SH | SF | IBB | Pos Summary | data-append-csv |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | Fernando Abad* | 35 | BAL | AL | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | abadfe01 |
| 1 | 2 | Cory Abbott | 25 | CHC | NL | 8 | 3 | 3 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0.333 | 0.333 | 0.333 | 0.667 | 81 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | /1H | abbotco01 |
| 2 | 3 | Albert Abreu | 25 | NYY | AL | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | abreual01 |
| 3 | 4 | Bryan Abreu | 24 | HOU | AL | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | abreubr01 |
| 4 | 5 | José Abreu | 34 | CHW | AL | 152 | 659 | 566 | 86 | 148 | 30 | 2 | 30 | 117 | 1 | 0 | 61 | 143 | 0.261 | 0.351 | 0.481 | 0.831 | 124 | 272 | 28 | 22 | 0 | 10 | 3 | *3D/5 | abreujo02 |

....

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get the table with this:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import Comment

import pandas as pd

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:101.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/101.0"
}
url = "https://www.baseball-reference.com/leagues/majors/2021-standard-batting.shtml"

with requests.Session() as s:
    comments = (
        BeautifulSoup(
            s.get(url, headers=headers).text,
            "lxml"
        ).find_all(string=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment))
    )
    table = pd.concat(
        pd.read_html(
            [c for c in comments if "players_standard_batting" in c][0]
        )
    )
    print(table)
    table.to_csv("batting.csv", index=False)
```

Output:

```
        Rk               Name  Age   Tm   Lg  ... HBP SH  SF IBB Pos Summary
0        1     Fernando Abad*   35  BAL   AL  ...   0  0   0   0           1
1        2        Cory Abbott   25  CHC   NL  ...   0  0   0   0         /1H
2        3       Albert Abreu   25  NYY   AL  ...   0  0   0   0           1
3        4        Bryan Abreu   24  HOU   AL  ...   0  0   0   0           1
4        5         José Abreu   34  CHW   AL  ...  22  0  10   3       *3D/5
...    ...                ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  .. ..  ..  ..         ...
1787  1720  Bruce Zimmermann*   26  BAL   AL  ...   0  0   0   0           1
1788  1721  Jordan Zimmermann   35  MIL   NL  ...   0  0   0   0          /1
1789  1722        Tyler Zuber   26  KCR   AL  ...   0  0   0   0           1
1790  1723        Mike Zunino   30  TBR   AL  ...   7  0   1   0         2/H
1791   NaN   LgAvg per 600 PA  NaN  NaN  NaN  ...   7  2   4   2         NaN

[1792 rows x 30 columns]
```

And the csv uploaded:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the html comment you extracted and parse it using BeautifulSoup,
then use CSS selector to get the rows with the `'data-append-csv'` in its attributes.

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import Comment, BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("https://www.baseball-reference.com/leagues/majors/2021-standard-batting.shtml")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

table_txt = [x.extract() for x in soup.find_all(string=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment)) if 'id="div_players_standard_batting"' in x][0]

table_soup = BeautifulSoup(table_txt, 'html.parser')

list_ = [{'index':index, 'data-append-csv':player['data-append-csv']} for index, player in enumerate(table_soup.select('td[data-append-csv]'), start=1)]

df = pd.DataFrame(list_)
```